# How to query for the intersection of two arrays in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to do something along these lines: `colleges.where("rotc.join(', ') & ?", rotc)`. Each College has an `rotc` string attribute (ex. `"Air Force, Army, Navy"`), and I want to see if it intersects with the rotc programs that the user has filtered for.

This [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0142hfdfc5) shows what I'm trying to build.

One problem I'm having is that I can't use the `join` method here. Another problem is that I don't think I could use the `&` method either.

How could I execute this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your form is set up such that it will return `params[:rotc]` with an array of checked values like `["Air Force", "Navy"]`, I would think you could do:

```
if params[:rotc] = []
  colleges = College.none #or maybe College.where("rotc = ''") 
else
  colleges = College.all
  params[:rotc].each |rotc| do
    colleges = colleges.where("rotc LIKE ?, "%#{rotc}%")
  end
end
```

There is probably a cleaner way, but maybe this will give you some ideas.

Comment: That works, thanks! I changed the code a little bit, but the key things were 1) the `.each` loop and 2) the `LIKE` operator with the `%`s.

Comment: You probably already figured this out, but the `College.where[..]` in the `each` block should have been `colleges.where[..]` - edited for posterity.